# How do I create a query template in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, function, templates

I have a query:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE firstname = 'joe'
```

I'd like to make a function to use this as a template.  I found some docs on functions, and they seem extremely obtuse for something so simple.  (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-createfunction.html)

What I'm looking for is something that should like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION getUserByFirstName(text) AS TEMPLATE (
  SELECT * FROM users WHERE firstname = $1
)
```

**How do I make query templates in postgres?**

---

P.S. I know this must be answered all over the place, but I tried searching ~12 different mixtures of the words "template" "query" "function" and "postgres" to no avail.

`WITH` is similar, but not globally defined or reusable (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/queries-with.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends on what you mean by "template":

If you want to be generic with respect to the parameter, you are already done (barring some syntax adjustments): simply omit the `TEMPLATE` and say `RETURNS users` instead.

If you want to be generic with respect to the column (`firstname`), you can do that with dynamic SQL.

If you want to be generic with respect to the table, you are out of luck: you cannot reasonably have a dynamic return type in PostgreSQL.

This is your function, written in a syntactically correct way:

```
CREATE FUNCTION getUserByFirstName(text) RETURNS users
   LANGUAGE sql AS
'SELECT * FROM users WHERE firstname = $1';
```

Comment: I'm just looking for the magic syntax.  I tried your suggestion, but this illusive syntax eludes me yet.  This doesn't compile: `CREATE FUNCTION getUserByFirstName(text) AS RETURNS users (
  SELECT * FROM users WHERE firstname = $1
)`.

It could be that db-fiddle is broken.  https://www.db-fiddle.com/

Comment: I have translated your function to proper SQL.

Answer (score 1):

I got this answer from xzilla on the Postgres Slack channel

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getUserByFirstName(text) RETURNS SETOF users AS $$ 
  SELECT * FROM users WHERE firstname = $1
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

It's very similar to the accepted answer.